# Annotating components in KiCad

Tags: schematics, kicad

I have a circuit with multiple stages and I wanted to number their components differently. For example, for the first stage I want the resistors to be R101, R102, etc. For the second one, R201, R202, and so on.

I know that there is an option related to this in the annotation tool (Annotation Choice states something like using sheet number*100), so I guess that to achieve this I should create multiple sheets. The thing is that I've done this but haven't reached the desired result, it just keeps using 100 and not 200, 300, etc.

So how can this be done properly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your procedure should be working.  A couple things to look for:

1. Are you resetting the annotation number?  In other words, is eeschema setting new numbers or perhaps just keeping the old ones.
   [image]
2. Look for the sheet number (bottom right of the sheet).  Is each number is different?  You can also see this in the "Page Settings" menu option:
   [image]